# Incremental batch delete and insert actions very slow in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, optimization, delete-row

I have the following stored procedure which deletes and inserts rows in a table. It is running slow.

I have read various proposals and i have implemented:

- Delete rows in batches and using derived table
- Disable FK
- Indexes on fields that are in the where clause.

So the way it should go is:

1. Tables have around 10 million records.
2. Every day i need to refresh around 15-30% of them. I use this SP to do it.

**Source:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spIncrementalUpdate]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @table_inc nvarchar(30),
    @table_target nvarchar(30),
    @table_date nvarchar(30),
    @field1 nvarchar(10),
    @field2 nvarchar(10)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @logmessage as nvarchar(2048)
    DECLARE @logdatacode as int
    DECLARE @cmd as nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @fromjulian nvarchar(10)
    DECLARE @datadate datetime
    DECLARE @datadate_str nvarchar(10)
    DECLARE @rows int
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)

    select @fromjulian = '114000'
    print 'Using ' + @fromjulian
    --
    -- GET THE ROW COUNT OF THE INC TABLE.
    --
    IF @field2 = ''
        BEGIN
            SET @cmd = N'SELECT @retval = count(*) from ' + 
                @table_inc + ' where ' + @field1 +' > ' + @fromjulian
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @cmd = N'SELECT @retval = count(*) from ' + 
                @table_inc + ' where ' + @field1 +' > ' + @fromjulian + 
                ' OR ' + @field2 +' > ' + @fromjulian
        END
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retval int OUTPUT'
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, @ParmDefinition, @retval = @rows OUTPUT
    --
    if @rows <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @logmessage = @table_inc + ' has ' + 
            cast(@rows as nvarchar(10)) + 
            ' rows after ' + @fromjulian + ', deleting'
        SET @logdatacode = 1000
        --
        -- Delete the records from original table based on @fromjulian
        --
        IF @field2 = ''
            BEGIN
                SET @cmd = N'delete ' + @table_target + 
                    ' from (select top(50000) * from ' + @table_target  +
                     ' where ' + @field1 + ' > ' + @fromjulian + 
                     ' order by ' + @field1 + ') ' + 
                     @table_target
                print @cmd
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @cmd = N'delete ' + @table_target + 
                    ' from (select top(50000) * from ' + 
                    @table_target  + 
                    ' where ' + @field1 + ' > ' + @fromjulian +  
                    ' OR ' + @field2 +' > ' + @fromjulian + 
                    ' order by ' + @field1 + ',' + @field2 + ') ' + 
                    @table_target
                print @cmd
            END 
        SELECT 1
        WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
        END
        --
        -- Inserting the records to target from INC table
        --
        IF @field2 = ''
            BEGIN
                SET @cmd = N'insert into ' + @table_target + 
                ' select * from ' + @table_inc + 
                ' where ' + @field1 +' > ' + cast(@fromjulian as nvarchar(10))
                print @cmd
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @cmd = N'insert into ' + @table_target + 
                ' select * from ' + @table_inc + 
                ' where ' + @field1 +' > ' + cast(@fromjulian as nvarchar(10)) + 
                ' OR ' + @field2 +' > ' + cast(@fromjulian as nvarchar(10))
                print @cmd
            END

        print @cmd
        EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @logmessage = 'NO ROWS IN ' + @table_inc + ' AFTER ' + cast(@fromjulian as nvarchar(10))
            SET @logdatacode = 1001
        END
    --
    -- LOG
    --
    INSERT INTO YLA_GROUP.[dbo].[sysssislog]
           ([event]
           ,[computer]
           ,[operator]
           ,[source]
           ,[sourceid]
           ,[executionid]
           ,[starttime]
           ,[endtime]
           ,[datacode]
           ,[databytes]
           ,[message])
     VALUES
           ('spIncrementalUpdate','','','',NEWID(),NEWID(),getdate(),getdate(),@logdatacode,null,@logmessage)
    print cast(@logdatacode as nvarchar(10)) + ' - ' + @logmessage
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are deleting rows in batches, you should remove the `ORDER BY` clause from your subquery because it is not necessary.

Here's the extract from your script:

```
IF @field2 = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @cmd = N'delete ' + @table_target + 
                   ' from (select top(50000) * from ' + @table_target  +
                   ' where ' + @field1 + ' > ' + @fromjulian + ') ' +  @table_target
        print @cmd
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @cmd = N'delete ' + @table_target + 
                   ' from (select top(50000) * from ' + @table_target  + 
                   ' where ' + @field1 + ' > ' + @fromjulian +  
                   ' OR ' + @field2 +' > ' + @fromjulian + ') ' + @table_target
        print @cmd
    END
```

Remember that sorting can be an expensive operation, and even more expensive if you remove (correctly in this case) indexes.

Beyond that, there's not much you can do. Also consider that using dynamic SQL, execution plans are **not cached**. So, every time you execute the command inside `@cmd` the *Query Engine* needs to calculate the optimal execution plan. Unfortunately, as far as I can see, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: I saw somewhere (i cant find the link now) that he used order by in a derived table to speed things up. Note that there are indexes enabled in the fields that i am ordering by ....

Comment: @e4rthdog at the moment I can't figure out how an ORDER BY can improve the performance. I mean, let's think about it, it is another operation to make even if you have a covering index. I think it's worth trying without the ORDER BY.

Comment: This is what i was talking about: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2009/05/22/DELETE-TOP-x-rows-avoiding-a-table-scan.aspx

Comment: @e4rthdog OK. But I'm still skeptic. Did you you compare the differences with and without order by? Did you compare execution plans? I'm pretty sure that you will see an expensive sort operator.

Comment: I think you are correct about it. Without order by seems faster...Although its slow enough still...

Comment: Yes it did ..Now i am running the sp with added logging to compare results and upload them too here to the the whole picture